# Hue and shared x-axis not working Seaborn facet grid

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm aiming to plot a stacked chart that displays normalised values from a pandas df. Using below, each unique value in `Item` has it's own row. I then aim to plot a stacked chart containing normalised values from `Label`, with `Num` along the x-axis.

However, hue seems to pass a different set of colours for each individual `Item`. They aren't consistent, for ex, `A` in `Up` is blue, while `A` in `Right` is green.

I'm also hoping to share the x-axis for `Num` is consistent for each `Item`. The values aren't aligned with the respective x-axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Num' : [1,2,1,2,3,2,1,3,2,2,1,2,3,3,1,3],
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','B','B','C','C','B','B','A','C','A','B','A','C','A'],   
    'Item' : ['Up','Left','Up','Left','Down','Right','Up','Down','Right','Down','Right','Up','Up','Right','Down','Left'],        
   })

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, 
                  row = 'Item', 
                  row_order = ['Up','Right','Down','Left'],                           
                  aspect = 2, 
                  height = 4, 
                  sharex = True,
                  legend_out = True
                  )

g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x = 'Num', hue = 'Label', multiple = 'fill', shrink = 0.8, binwidth = 1)
g.add_legend()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FacetGrid` directly can be tricky; it is basically doing a groupb-by and for loop over the axes, and it does not track any function-specific state that would be needed to make sure that the answer to questions like "what order should be used for each hue level" is the same in each facet. So you would need to supply that information somehow (i.e. `hue_order` or passing a palette dictionary). In fact, there is a warning in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) to this effect.

But you generally *don't* need to use `FacetGrid` directly; you can use one of the figure-level functions, which do all of the bookkeeping for you to make sure that information is aligned across facets. Here you would use `displot`:

```
sns.displot(
    data=df, x="Num", hue="Label",
    row='Item', row_order=['Up','Right','Down','Left'],
    multiple="fill", shrink=.8, discrete=True,
    aspect=4, height=2,
)
```

[image]

Note that I've made one other change to your code here, which is to use `discrete=True` instead of `binwidth=1`, which is what I think you want.

Comment: Maybe it could be helpful if `g.map_dataframe()` issued some warning reminding to `displot` when called with `histplot` and related functions? (And maybe the ylabel could be different  for `multiple='fill'`, something like "Proportion" or so?)

Comment: It's not really possibly to infer whether or not a particular usage of `FacetGrid` with an axes-level function will or will not be a problem ... most of the figure-level functions do that internally ... it's just a matter of having the data in the right format/having the right metadata. The best I can do is signal strongly in the docs that direct usage of `FacetGrid` is advanced / something you should do only if you know what you're doing.